# Block vars vs local vars visibility. How to pass var name and value via one param to lambda?

Tags: ruby, lambda, eval, block, visibility

Here is validation list and lambda, which validates an object:

```
valid_specs = ["instrumentalist", "dj", "producer", "songwriter", "teacher"]
validate_obj = lambda do |obj_name, valid|
  obj = eval obj_name
  p "no such #{obj_name} `#{obj}`" unless valid.include? obj
end
```

Passing local var to lambda is OK:

```
spec_id = "tacher"
validate_obj.call("spec_id", valid_specs) #=> no such spec_id `tacher`
```

But passing block var causes an error:

```
specs = ["teacher", "songwriter", "producer"]
specs.each do |spec_id|
  valid_obj.call("spec_id", valid_specs)
end
#=>:in `eval': undefined local variable or method `spec_id' for main:Object (NameError)
```

---

It doesn't seems obvious to me. I'd like to know the reasons for that and how to achieve my goal not to pass var name and var value via two params `"spec_id",spec_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lambda doesn’t have a reference to it because the it doesn’t have access to the scope in which it was called (unless that scope happens to be the same as the one it was defined in, as it is in the first case, which is just a side-effect).

The only way to give it access is to pass the [`binding`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-binding) of the calling scope and call [`eval`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Binding.html#method-i-eval) on it:

```
f = ->(name) { eval name }
'foo'.tap { |x| f.('x') }  #=> #<NameError: undefined local variable or method `x' for main:Object>

f = ->(binding, name) { binding.eval name }
'foo'.tap { |x| f.(binding, 'x') }  #=> "foo"
```

The only other way is, as you say, to explicitly pass both the variable name and value as two parameters.

Comment: Maybe not that beautiful but totally working solution I was looking for. Also I had adopted the short syntax (`->` = `lambda` and `.` = `.call`). Does anyone know another ways to pass var name and var value via one param?

Comment: @RubyLover There is *no* way to do it with only one parameter except by “cheating” and including both objects in one (e.g. passing an array containing both).

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially trying to do this:

```
myfunc = lambda {puts eval("word"), eval("x")}

words = ["teacher", "songwriter", "producer"]

words.each do |word|
  x = 10
  myfunc.call
end
```

But word and x are local variables of the each() block, so the lambda block can't see them.  Blocks can see their *enclosing scope*--but they can't see inside other scopes contained in their enclosing scope. This works:

```
myfunc = lambda {puts eval("word"), eval("x")}

word = "hello"
x = 10

myfunc.call

--output:--
hello
10
```

Here is a more interesting version:

```
func1 = lambda {puts eval "x"}
func2 = lambda {puts x}
x = "hello"

func1.call
func2.call

--output:--
hello

1.rb:23:in `block in <main>': undefined local variable or method `x' for main:Object (NameError)
    from 1.rb:27:in `call'
    from 1.rb:27:in `<main>'
```

It looks like the binding for eval() is "bigger" than the closure for the second block: the binding for eval() is the whole enclosing scope outside the block; but the closure formed by the second block only closes over variables that were in the enclosing scope at the time the block was created.

That seems to make sense in light of this example:

```
b = binding

myfunc = lambda {puts eval("word", b), eval("x", b)}

word = "hello"
x = 10

myfunc.call 


--output:--
hello
10
```

So when you write:

```
myfunc = lambda {puts eval("word"), eval("x")}

word = "hello" 
x = 10

myfunc.call
```

...it's as if the lambda block is closing over an invisible b variable, which eval() uses by default, and then the code essentially does this: `b.word = "hello"; b.x = 10`.  That works the same way here:

```
word = nil
x = nil

myfunc = lambda {puts word, x}

word = "hello"
x = 10

myfunc.call 

--output:--
hello
10
```

In other words, a block closes over variables--not values, and the variables that a block closes over can be altered by code that comes after the block.

> Does anyone know another ways to pass var name and var value via one param?

There are many ruby objects that can hold more than one piece of data: arrays, hashes, Structs, instances of custom classes, etc.

```
valid_specs = ["instrumentalist", "dj", "producer", "songwriter", "teacher"]

validate_obj = lambda do |data|
  obj_name = data.var_name
  obj = eval obj_name, data.binding
  p "no such #{obj_name} `#{obj}`" unless valid_specs.include? obj
end

MyData = Struct.new(:var_name, :binding)
specs = ["teacher", "sweeper", "producer"]

specs.each do |spec_id|
  mydata = MyData.new("spec_id", binding)
  validate_obj.call(mydata)
end

--output:--
"no such spec_id `sweeper`"
```

But that code can also be written more simply like this:

```
valid_specs = ["instrumentalist", "dj", "producer", "songwriter", "teacher"]

validate_obj = lambda do |spec_id|
  p "no such spec_id `#{spec_id}`" unless valid_specs.include? spec_id
end

specs = ["teacher", "sweeper", "producer"]

specs.each do |spec_id|
  validate_obj.call(spec_id)
end
```